# Android Studio 2.0 Preview upgrade problems

Tags: android, android-studio

Just updated to Android Studio 2.0 preview (not realising it was a major update I was installing), and am having issues.  Right from the first line of build.gradle, which is highlighted with an error:

[image]

And lots of stuff in the event log:

[image]

And pretty much nothing is recognised in the code itself:

[image]

The upgrade completed without apparent issue, so any idea what's up and how to fix it?

Comment: try "invalidate caches and restart"

Comment: Thanks, exactly right.  If you put it as an answer I can mark it correct!

Comment: glad this worked - added an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do "File" -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart".